# NetSuit To Big Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, netsuite, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am looking for some solution on Google cloud if there is any service help to migrate or setup a connection to transfer NetSuit ( oracle ERP Platform) data to big query?
I thought of using data fusion using jdbc driver however I am unsure about it. Also, how about using composer?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data Fusion which is a fully managed, cloud-native data integration service that helps you efficiently build and manage ETL/ELT pipelines. It provides a graphical interface to build and manage data pipelines that ingest data from various sources and transform that data. You can use Data Fusion to move data from NetSuit to BigQuery using JDBC driver. You can read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/architect-your-data-lake-google-cloud-data-fusion-and-composer).